# Issue with sorting by post date and custom post type

Tags: wp-query, date

I'm having a strange issue with sorting by post date.

I created a slideshow post type and it does by default order by post date but If I change the date posted through the admin the order doesn't update in the query, but it does get updated in the admin.

The Post Type

```
/* Slideshow Post Type */
add_action('init', 'slide_init');
function slide_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Slides', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Slide', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'slide'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Slide'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Slide'),
        'new_item' => __('New Slide'),
        'view_item' => __('View Slide'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Slides'),
        'not_found' => __('No slides found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No slides found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Homepage Slides'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
    ); 
    register_post_type('slide', $args);
}
```

The Query

```
// Slideshow Query
$slideshow_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'slide',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
);
$slideshow = new WP_Query( $slideshow_args );
```

Edit - -

I found out this has something to do with this line of code.

```
$slideshow_post_count = $slideshow->post_count; 

<?php if ($slideshow_post_count > 1) : ?>
<div class="controls span6">
    <span class="next"></span>
    <span class="pause"></span>
    <span class="prev"></span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you got something modifying your query elsewhere. Plugin?

Comment: That's what I thought I removed them all. It orders in a very strange way. It will make a post first sometimes when I change the date manually. I tested and right now the order is Aug21, Aug17, Aug18. It still updates some posts when I change the date so this must be part of the query. 

I should mention I just updated to 3.6.

Comment: @GhostToast I found If i remove the line above the query runs normally, but I don't know how else I could include this?

Comment: I tried replacing post_count with found_posts, same issue.

Comment: i'd be `var_dump`ing the wp_query object to see what it was really trying to do. No caching, all plugins disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you played with the other arguments available to WP_Query?

```
$slideshow_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'slide',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'orderby'        => 'post_date',
    'order'          => 'DESC'
);
$slideshow = new WP_Query( $slideshow_args );
```

Comment: It's something with my controls. See my edit.

Comment: Hmm I think you may be onto the right path but it's not the controls themselves. Can you remove all control code and try printing out the titles and dates raw to narrow it down?

Comment: I'm the biggest idiot, my controls are backwards... Thanks for your help anyhow.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, I know your pain. If I helped at all please mark my answer correct.